# Resue from Mysql unique index duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, concurrency, indexing

I am trying to fix a double request problem: when browser spawn two or more identical requests to server and they got processed on different app servers.

In this case one of two requests hits:

```
Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry '...' 
for key 'index_purchases_on_site_id_and_order_number_and_email
```

There is rescue code afterwards that selects existing record instead that uses the same parameters as insert request:

```
select * from purchases where site_id = ? and order_number = ? and email = ?
```

But it doesn't find anything in database.

A fragment from DB query log:

```
  SQL (1.3ms)   BEGIN
  ......
  Purchase Create (0.0ms)   Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry '1887-100264587-9z1CIIDsH2a21+AEEH2OR9LsndO3oIS4D4Am1U5XJ04=
' for key 'index_purchases_on_site_id_and_order_number_and_email': INSERT INTO `purchases` (`order_date`, `referrer`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `encrypted_email`, `visitor_id`, `order_number`, `coupon_code`, `subtotal`, `customer_id`, `site_id`, `ip_address`) VALUES('2013-01-14 20:57:47', 'https://www.bonobos.com/b/checkout', '2013-01-14 20:57:47', '2013-01-14 20:57:47', '9z1CIIDsH2a21+AEEH2OR9LsndO3oIS4D4Am1U5XJ04=\n', 15813843, '100264587', '', 218.0, NULL, 1887, '12.106.186.6')
  Purchase Load (0.5ms)   SELECT * FROM `purchases` WHERE (order_number = '100264587' AND site_id = 1887 AND encrypted_email = '9z1CIIDsH2a21+AEEH2OR9LsndO3oIS4D4Am1U5XJ04=\n') LIMIT 1
  SQL (18.0ms)   ROLLBACK
```

How is this possible?

Comment: do you use transactions?

Comment: Yes, I am using them. Transaction is important for the app logic. Can still do it without removing transaction?

Comment: The Schema and DML commands that result in this error would be helpful.

Comment: Then it's not clear for me: when you do the `select` query?

Comment: Added a fragment from SQL log. Hope it helps.

Comment: I see only a one thing strange. In error string the `\n` is converted in one new line, and in other place correclty `\n` instead. I don't know if it could be the problem.